# VLookup not working on full numbered Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I created a Google Spreadsheet (File Name **Product Test**) and I have an ID field on **column A** which contains the word ID plus some letters and numbers (Example "ID-KNYT-12345"). The KNYT part is different per ID, some KNYT some DMXF etc.

So in **column B** I added a custom formula (Sample below) which processes the ID. If KNYT only numbers are kept. If DMXF the DMXF part is included plus the numbers.

I then have a vlookup/importrange formula on **column C** which is supposed to use the converted value in **column B** to lookup the value from another sheet and retrieve a certain information.

The problem is if the converted value contains all numbers like **12345** the vlookup fails, "Did not find value in lookup evaluation". If the converted value contains letters and numbers like **DMXF-25452** the lookup works. If I manually type 12345 on **column A** the lookup works. Why would the lookup say it didn't find a result when the value is there? More details below

- I checked, all cells involved are in format Number>"AUTOMATIC".
- I checked, the value 12345 is definitely found on the other sheet (Imported Range)
- I checked these values online, I found no hidden characters or spaces
- The data is from an email with attached Excel file. I don't download the file, I just click to preview it and copy-paste the entire table over to my Product Test spreadsheet

The custom Formula:

```
function Convert(Thevalue) 
{
  Thevalue = Thevalue.toString().replace("ID-KNYT-", "");
  Thevalue = Thevalue.toString().replace("ID-DMXF-", "DMXF-");

  if (Thevalue == "DMXF-2245"){Thevalue = "Evaluated";}
  if (Thevalue == "DMXF-3268"){Thevalue = "Pending";}

  return Thevalue;
}
```

The Vlookup (Not actual sheet url just a sample)

```
VLOOKUP($B1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/feiugsdfjhsdkjfhiesdfjh-p-dsflkjgsdf/edit#gid=000222333","sheet1!$A:$C"),3,FALSE)
```

UPDATE: This seem to fix it for me. Looks like if the return value is all numbers and no letters it is a NaN issue

```
  if (!isNaN(Thevalue))
  {
    return Number(Thevalue);
  }
  else
  {
    return Thevalue;
  }
```

Comment: Can you wrap up a [sample](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) sheet? And the custom function can be done with REGEX functions. Maybe you need to wrap it inside a VALUE so it is a number?

Comment: So sorry, but by REGEX you mean in App Script or through formula? There's over hundreds of different string conversions (The above is just a sample) so I can't fit in formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom function returns text strings. The `vlookup()` function does not consider the number `123` and the text string `"123"` equal. To make it work, convert the lookup keys to text with `to_text()`, like this:

`=vlookup( to_text($B1), Sheet1!$A:$C, columns(Sheet1!$A:$C), false )`

As RemcoE33 said, the custom function seems superfluous, because the same thing can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula that employs `regexreplace()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( regexreplace( to_text(A2:A), "ID(?:-KNYT)?-", "" ) )`

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid **TO_TEXT()** didn't solve it. What you said about **123** and **"123"** does make sense since if I do return **Number(TheValue);** it solves that issue. The thing is I am expecting hundreds of different return values, some contains both letters and numbers and some just numbers. So I can't use **Number()** as if the return value contains letters like DMXF-3268 it would cause an error too

Comment: If I add IFERROR to the VLOOKUP and **VALUE()**, it works too but makes some of my already long formulas even longer.  Is there a way in App Script to check if a value contains letters before returning? **VLOOKUP(VALUE($B1),IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/feiugsdfjhsdkjfhiesdfjh-p-dsflkjgsdf/edit#gid=000222333","sheet1!$A:$C"),3,FALSE)**

Comment: I edited my question, I found some workaround I hope this works permanently

Comment: The other way is to use `String()` on all the keys you return from the custom function, and then apply `to_text()` to your search keys.